# Open Weather data in React using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, reactjs

Given the [Open Weather Map current weather data API](http://openweathermap.org/current), I'm trying to pull in current weather data into my React.js app using ajax, extract the current temp value for a given city, and then render that value in my component.

The test JSON data that I'm working with is at this url:
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5391997&units=imperial

```
var CityGrid = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5391997', 
      // ^^ this should get a variable where id=5391997 is set
      dataType: 'json',  
      success: function(data) {
          this.setState({temp: data.main.temp});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState:function(){
    return{
      cities:[
        { 
          name: "San Francisco",
          id: 5391997,
          temp: 50,  // << this should receive value from ajax call
          UTCOffset:-7,
          address: 999 Nathan Lane,
          phone: 555-5555
        },
        // 12 more city objects in this array, removed for brevity
    ]}
},
render: function() {
    console.log(this.state.temp); // << this returns the right temp
    // for San Francisco, because I hardcoded the value into the url
    return(
        <div className="city-grid">
        {this.state.cities.map(function(city,i){
          return(
            <CityRow key={i} name={city.name} temp={city.temp}
            UTCOffset={city.UTCOffset} address={city.address} 
            phone={city.phone}/>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = CityGrid;
```

My Questions:

1. How to extract the temp value? In my render function, console.log returns the JSON object, which means the data has been bound and can be accessed in my render function. However, when I try to get the temperature, which I expect to be something like `this.state.data.main.temp`, I get errors that "data is undefined." I would then like to be able to set this value in my cities object at               `id: 5391997,` for each of the 12 cities.

**UPDATE** ^^ This is solved: @dkurbz suggestion to set the state as temp in my ajax success method works fine for me.

2. I'm also having a challenge with how to set the url uniquely for each city. In my ajax call, there is `id=5391997`, which I would like to get from the cities objects and change my ajax url to something like 'baseURl' + this.props.id + '&units=imperial'. I'm at a total loss about how to do this.

**UPDATE** ^^ This is where I'm currently stuck.

Comment: Can you post the result of that console.log? and which line do you get the error on?

Comment: Sure, in my render function is console.log(this.state.data.main.temp), my console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined"

Comment: Probably because you don't set data in your initialState. Before the ajax comes back, this.state.data is undefined.

Comment: Have you even tried the code I posted? Because I just ran it in a jsfiddle, and it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some errors with this, but I think it should get you pretty close.

```
var React = require("react");
var $ = require("jquery");

var City = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        units: React.PropTypes.string
    },

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: {},
            fetching: false
        };
    },

    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            units: "imperial"
        };
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div class="city">
                {this.state.fetching ? "Downloading data..." : this.state.data.main.temp}
            </div>
        );
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id="+this.props.id+"&units="+this.props.units,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                this.setState({fetching: true});
            },
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(xhr, status, err.toString());
            },
            complete: function () {
                this.setState({fetching: false});
            },
            context: this
        });
    }
});

var CityGrid = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        cityIds: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
    },

    renderCity: function (cityId) {
        return <City id={cityId} />;
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div class="city-grid">
                {this.props.cityIds.map(this.renderCity)}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

That being said... this isn't The Right Solution. The ajax call should be moved outside of the component (have you looked into Flux, or some other library that would give you the concept of a Model or a Store?), the returned "data" should then be transformed/normalized into a flat structure somehow, and then passed to the City component as props (and only the props that make sense/that you care about). This way, the City component can be agnostic about where its data comes from. You should, in theory, be able to render a City with some data from another source, multiple sources, dummy data, etc. But I wasn't going to go and code all that for you ;)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I'm wondering, how do the city Ids get used in the url? I dont see where the cityIds array (which looks like `var cityIds = [5391997, 5809844, 4853799, ...]` goes. Also, each of my 12 city objects has 6 attributes and looks like this: `cities: [ { name, temp, weather-icon, UTCOffset, address, url, phone, callphone } ]`. I'm trying to find a way to make your code work in mine.

Comment: You pass the CityGrid component an array of cityIds. The CityGrid renders each City, and passes the City an id. The City makes the ajax call using that id. Once you get this working, you can add in that additional metadata (name, weather-icon, etc) into each city object (so it will end up an array of city objects, not just an array of numbers that are city ids, but start simple). What is the problem you're getting with this code exactly?

Comment: I'm getting the errors:"_ Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `cityIds` was not specified in `CityGrid`._` as well as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` in the render function. So I'm wondering where the array of cityIds go and how each city object receives the Id. Then I'm also wondering why you're rendering them as `{this.props.cityIds.map(this.renderCity)}` and how it compares to my original state setting `{this.state.cities.map(function(city,i){  return( <CityRow key={i} temp={city.temp}/> );  })}`

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, no? You have to pass the prop "cityIds" to the component "CityGrid" ... This is a very basic and core React concept.

As far as the map functions, they are equivalent, so I don't really understand the question? (actually, mine's missing the key, which it probably should have)

Answer (score 1):

Before you `setState` on `data`, `this.state.data` is undefined. You can fix this by either not rendering anything from `this.state.data` until it's defined, or set `data: {}` in your `getInitialState`.

Comment: OK, I've instantiated `data: {}`, above my cities array in the `getInitialState` function. Now my console.log in the render function will only go so far as `this.state.data.main`. When I attempt to log `this.state.data.main.temp` I get the same "_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined_" error.

Comment: right because `this.state.data.main` is also undefined at this point. So you could either set `getInitialState` to `data: { main: { temp: 0 } }` or check if it's defined: `if (this.state.data.main) { console.log(this.state.data.main.temp); }`

Comment: But from the ajax call I would just set the state in a meaningful way, not necessarily how it's returned. i.e. just `setState({ temp: data.main.temp })` and then just render `this.state.temp`.

Comment: thank you, that is great progress. but it appears that I can't use the value inside my render function as `temp={this.state.temp}`, presumable because of how I'm mapping `{this.state.cities.map(function(city,i) { ...... }` for each city. I'm still feeling quite stuck.

Comment: ok so taking a step back, what is the component supposed to render? The temperature for 12 different cities? If so I would just loop through each one and add an entry of its temp to the state. Like this https://gist.github.com/djkirby/f04ff0d8d044694cbec7

Comment: I omitted the others for brevity, but each "cities" object has 6 attributes: `{name, temp, weather-icon, UTCOffset, address, url, phone, callphone}` and so I'm rendering them as shown above, in the form: `return(
            <CityRow key={i} name={city.name} temp={city.temp} weather={city.weather} url={city.url} UTCOffset={city.UTCOffset} address={city.address} phone={city.phone} callphone={city.callphone}/>
          );`